# Geoserver Mapfish Printing : Error while generating PDF

Tags: geoserver, printing, mapfish

I have a Geoserver application with Geoserver 2.8 snapshot version and Printing-plugin 2.8 version. When I click a print button on map, it generates the below error

```
Error while generating PDF:
DocumentException: org.mapfish.print.InvalidJsonValueException: spec.layers[0].baseURL has an invalid value: http://myIP:8081/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS& (spec.layers[0].baseURL has an invalid value: http://myIP:8081/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&)
at org.mapfish.print.map.readers.HTTPMapReader.checkSecurity(HTTPMapReader.java:136)
at org.mapfish.print.map.readers.HTTPMapReader.<init>(HTTPMapReader.java:76)
at org.mapfish.print.map.readers.TileableMapReader.<init>(TileableMapReader.java:40)
at org.mapfish.print.map.readers.WMSMapReader.<init>(WMSMapReader.java:97)
at org.mapfish.print.map.readers.WMSMapReader.<init>(WMSMapReader.java:45)
at org.mapfish.print.map.readers.WMSMapReader$Factory.create(WMSMapReader.java:83)
at org.mapfish.print.map.readers.MapReaderFactoryFinder.create(MapReaderFactoryFinder.java:36)
at org.mapfish.print.map.MapChunkDrawer.renderImpl(MapChunkDrawer.java:116)
at org.mapfish.print.ChunkDrawer.render(ChunkDrawer.java:55)
at org.mapfish.print.ChunkDrawer.tableLayout(ChunkDrawer.java:49)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.ColumnText.goComposite(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPRow.writeCells(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.ColumnText.goComposite(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDocument.addPTable(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDocument.add(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.Document.add(Unknown Source)
at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.Page$1.add(Page.java:76)
at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.MapBlock.render(MapBlock.java:78)
at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.Page.render(Page.java:73)
at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.MainPage.render(MainPage.java:63)
at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.Layout.render(Layout.java:59)
at org.mapfish.print.output.AbstractOutputFormat.doPrint(AbstractOutputFormat.java:30)
at org.mapfish.print.output.PdfOutputFactory.print(PdfOutputFactory.java:62)
at org.mapfish.print.MapPrinter.print(MapPrinter.java:184)
at org.mapfish.print.servlet.MapPrinterServlet.doCreatePDFFile(MapPrinterServlet.java:340)
at org.mapfish.print.servlet.MapPrinterServlet.createAndGetPDF(MapPrinterServlet.java:159)
at org.mapfish.print.servlet.MapPrinterServlet.doGet(MapPrinterServlet.java:90)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:436)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:177)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:509)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.mapfish.print.InvalidJsonValueException: spec.layers[0].baseURL has an invalid value: http://myIP:8081/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&
at org.mapfish.print.map.readers.HTTPMapReader.checkSecurity(HTTPMapReader.java:133)
... 62 more
```

I have added my ip address in the host section of the config.yaml file also. Help me in finding where I am going wrong.

Comment: fix the URL for spec.layers[0].baseURL has an invalid value: http://myIP:8081/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&

Comment: @iant - Don't know how to fix the URL. Can u explain how to fix it, what may be the problem?

Comment: since we don't know the *correct* URL for your map server you are really on your own here